# Installing Canon ip2600 printer drivers on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: printing, canon

I followed instructions from serveral pages (e.g. [here](http://technostripe.com/getting-the-canon-pixma-ip2600-to-work-on-ubuntu/)) to install Canon ip2600 printer drivers that were discussed for Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier as follows:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2600series

After that, the printer is listed and a printer properties window can be open. Trying to print anything fails with a message "Processing - Waiting for printer to become available." next to printer state.

Does anybody know how to get the printer to work? I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on 64 bit.

Answer (score 4):

After updating to Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit), I got my Canon ip2600 printer to work with the canon-trunk repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2600series
```

Before that, I also tried the Gutenprint driver, which installed fine, but still no reaction from the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Ubuntu on my ThinkPad X61 and Acer Aspire circa 2010; tried many wats but the following worked:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2600series
```