# Will I lose Canon iP2600 printer support if I upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: printing

I run 14.04.5 and currently have Canon iP2600 printer support after using the advice here: [Installing Canon ip2600 printer drivers on ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230039/installing-canon-ip2600-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10) .
I have found out by doing an install of 14.04 on another PC that that process will not now work. 
My concern is that if I upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 on this PC that I will lose printer my Canon iP2600 printer support.
What does the team advise please?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in answering my own question.
However I had installed 16.04 in addition to the existing 14.04 on my PC.
I have in the last 30 minutes found a solution here http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/ that works for my printer on 16.04.